# Creating a Type Object in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

Can  we create a Type class object in Java generics like `T t = new T();`

Here is my code,

```
public class Graph<T extends NeighbourInt<T>> {

    Map<String, List<T>> adjecencyList;

    public Graph() {
        adjecencyList = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addEdge(String vertex1, String vertex2, int weight) {
        if (adjecencyList.containsKey(vertex1)) {
           List<T> neg = adjecencyList.get(vertex1);
           neg.add(new T (vertex2, weight));
       } else {
           List<T> neg = new ArrayList<>();
           neg.add(new T(vertex2, weight));
           adjecencyList.put(vertex1, neg);
       }
    }
}
```

My NeighbourInt interface

```
public interface NeighbourInt<T> extends Comparable<T> {

    public String getVertex();

    public void setVertex(String vertex);

    public int getWeight();

    public void setWeight(int weight);

}
```

Is there possible way to initiate an object like new T(); in Java Generics?

Comment: No it's not possible, as at runtime, generics disappear. You can use `Class.newInstance` to perform this

Comment: You _do not want_ to create a new `T` you actually just want to use that parameter `T n` that you pass in.  i.e. `neg.add(n)`

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, I corrected as addEdge(String vertex1, String vertex2, int weight){...}. I want to add an T type new Object that implements NeighbourInt properties.

Comment: Alright let me clarify again.  You _do not want_ `addEdge(String vertex1, String vertex2, int weight)` you want what you originally had.  Make the caller make a new `T` for you.

Comment: Yeah, I initially tried that. But I wondered whether there is a way to make the constructors also generic safe to use as new T() or new T(String vertex, int weight). From all of the replies I think there is no such a way. Thanks for the quick replies :)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not yet (because of erasure, again)

But, the constructor of `Graph` could take in a generator that creates a `T` from (String,int); call this generator when you need to create a new `T`.

In java 8, you can do

```
public Graph( BiFunction<String,Integer,T> generator )
```

and when you need to create a `T`, do `generator.apply(string,integer)`

Say you have a constructor in a subtype of NeighbourInt

```
public Foo(String, int)
```

you can do

```
new Graph<>( Foo::new )
```

Comment: 1 plus for java 8 stuff. It can help the situation I think. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @sandaru.ny - well, you don't need java8 for this problem; it'll just be more verbose in java 7.

Answer (score 2):

No. Actually, `T` is the parameter for the generic type, not a class.

For example:

```
public interface NeighbourInt extends Comparable<NeighbourInt> {
    // ...
}
```

The code above is declaring the `NeighbourInt` as a `Comparable` with parameter `NeighbourInt`.

As the `Comparable` interface is defined as:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    int compareTo(T o);
}
```

the parametrized `Comparable<NeighbourInt>` would be equivalent to an interface having the method:

```
int compareTo(NeighbourInt o);
```

So the `NeighbourInt` declared above is inheriting that method.

**EDIT:** Think of a generic class as a class that is a "factory of classes", as a class that manufactures other classes. So only create a generic class when you need to have many "manufactured" classes with different types as a parameter.

So declaring:

```
public class Graph<T extends NeighbourInt> {
    // ...
}
```

only makes sense if you're having many "types of graphs", like:

```
Graph<Node> graph;
Graph<WeightedNode> weightedGraph;
// and so on...
```

If you're only having a graph of `NeighbourInt`s, then your first option is to write:

```
public class Graph {
    // this is where you set the generic parameter
    Map<String, List<NeighbourInt>> adjecencyList;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah its true :)  But I wanted to add a new Type T object to the list adjecencyList which can have objects of Type T. Is it possible??

Comment: Maybe you're overusing generics. Why do you need to declare your `Graph` class as a generic type? Updated my answer.

Comment: The adjcencyList actually use the NeighbourInt methods only. But a there was a new type of having class that has few more methods too. I think I got your point. It would be nice to have a decorator class with new methods with an implementation of the NeighbourInt interface. Thanx for the reply :)